# Determine font color in AI

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, fonts

I have an Adobe Illustrator file made-up primarily of text.  How do I find out the exact color of a given piece of text?  For example, I have the word "PEN" in a certain blue.  How do I find out the exact blue that is?

Comment: This is such a basic question that could be answered in seconds using a quick search. Click the color picker tool

Comment: Thanks Mr. Saucier.  Excuse me.  I thought this site was to help all kinds of users; not just professionals.  I am doing my best to try and learn Illustrator.

Comment: @bobkap, I noticed you havn't accepted an answer on a single question you have asked. Accepting answers is an important part of the Q&A format here. You can read more about it in the [Help Center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/asking). If you don't feel there are any adequate answers you can always edit your questions to add more details or even add a [bounty](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)!

Comment: Also, Zach is correct that this is a very basic question, although basic questions aren't necessarily off-topic, [questions should be well researched and show a bit of effort](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

If you select the text, your fill colour square in the tool palette will change to be the same colour. Double click on the fill square to open the colour picker dialogue and you'll have all the info about that colour.